Sending Requests from the Frontend on one domain to Backend on Another Domain
I have the website on the hosting (e.g. https://example.com), and I have a page on this domain, that makes request to the backend, located on another domain (e.g. https://example-2.com located on AWS EC2).
Both domains have SSL certificates (I guess, both from Let's Encrypt).
For some reason I am getting Bad Request Error.
On frontend I get net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.
On backend I see the following:

72.2xx.87.250 - - [17/Oct/2024 04:46:07] code 400, message Bad request version ('L·/¬Æc¹B²\x03sCveÅú®\x186_½4\x1anù³»0\x10ÔF£¬ªJÍgÁD¶#1!\x8blVÅ\x1a\x16s|Å\x94Bæ\x0eç\x94\x9e') 72.2xx.87.250 - - [17/Oct/2024 04:46:07] "\x16\x03\x01\x06ø\x01\x00\x06ô\x03\x03\x9a"\x12dÌ¦#\x92Ë\x82è\x0d\x964Khwöã6\x9azãê.\x13i¨Åuëí \x93í\x1aØd\x9f´pr:t\x84ZI\x164¨Rü\x85%9[¢ië\x9f\x97<\x18Á_\x00 jj\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03À+À/...\x88=K§wÜw1RHÜ6ÅVüwchb\x8bkpª\x07ufÌ±8©\x92ó©k\x09L·/¬Æc¹B²\x03sCveÅú®\x186_½4\x1anù³»0\x10ÔF£¬ªJÍgÁD¶#1!\x8blVÅ\x1a\x16s|Å\x94Bæ\x0eç\x94\x9e" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST - 72.2xx.87.250 - - [17/Oct/2024 04:46:07] code 400, message Bad request version ('*HYçs\x9dRGö¢ºÝ\x90o\x00â¿Ð') 72.2xx.87.250 - - [17/Oct/2024 04:46:07] "\x16\x03\x01\x06Ø\x01\x00\x06Ô\x03\x03®¹zb\x84\x1c\x92\x97º»Ü£ùn\x1a'\\\x1b¨Ù\x11x\x1c\x06\x1dyÓWÕ...Ñ\x9bÍ...

I understand that the issue might be in encryption, but I have no clue how to tackle this.
I am using CORS for Flask.
I tried to make requests https -> http  and https -> https, but the result is the same.
They have Phusion Passenger on the hosting, and i have Nginx on my EC2.
My front looks like
fetch('https://example-2.com:5000/pred', { 
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            },
                            body: JSON.stringify({ file: base64Data })
                        })
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .then(data => {
                                console.log('Response from server:', data);
                                loader.style.display = 'none';
                                predictionResult.style.display = 'flex';
                                predictionResult.innerHTML = 'The prediction is <br/><b>' + data['prediction'] + '</b>';
                                submitButton.disabled = false;
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
                                submitButton.disabled = false;
                            });

My back looks like
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import base64
from flask_cors import cors

application = Flask(__name__)
CORS(application)

@application.route('/pred', methods=['POST'])
def handle_post_request():

...
    return jsonify({'prediction': prediction})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')

I do not have power over the hosting, where frontend is located, but on my EC2 I installed Ngnix like it was described here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-nginx
And then got Let's Encrypt SSL from, using https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=pip
Both domains are Let's Encrypted.
UPD. I realized that my NginX is set up wrongly (I guess), but I cannot fix this.
I set it up in a way, that other server can make request with 200 status, but for some reason, client (browser) cannot - it still has bad request.

Can you provide some code or configuration showing how you are trying to request  https://example-2.com in the back-end and also how you are forwarding the returned result  to the front-end? Are you using custom code or a module? Or are you using Ngnix to achieve this? Also, try to add the language or framework you are using as a tag in your question.

It looks like your trying to talk TLS to a non-TLS service. Your server, or client, or both, are incorrectly configured.

@MarinosAn, I made the changes to the post. It just fetch from JS to the application working on Flask - just endpoint that returns the result to frontend. Flask is working on 5000 port, and Ngnix listens on 80 aтв 443 by default, as I understand.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I think so, but both parties are encrypted via Let's encrypt, and that is why I am confused.

I figured it out! It was necessary to identify headers in the Nginx configuration file; now everything works smoothly!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
